# Native games on Linux is running perfectly, but games ran through Wine are crashing pc

Tags: arch-linux, wine, wayland

Neofetch output:

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 

Host: X99 Kernel: 6.7.5-zen1-1-zen 

Uptime: 13 mins Packages: 903 (pacman), 10 (flatpak) 

Shell: bash 5.2.26 

Resolution: 1600x900 

DE: Plasma 5.27.10 WM: kwin 

Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 

Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 

Terminal: konsole 

CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2650 v4 (24) @ 2.900GHz 

GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E 

Memory: 3613MiB / 15827MiB
```

Wine version:wine-tkg-staging-fsync-git 9.2.r3.g29b947b8-327
Videocard driver: amdgpu(latest)
When crashed, even emergency reboot button on case doesn't work, i guess its cpu problem

Neofetch output:

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 

Host: X99 Kernel: 6.7.5-zen1-1-zen 

Uptime: 13 mins Packages: 903 (pacman), 10 (flatpak) 

Shell: bash 5.2.26 

Resolution: 1600x900 

DE: Plasma 5.27.10 WM: kwin 

Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 

Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 

Terminal: konsole 

CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2650 v4 (24) @ 2.900GHz 

GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E 

Memory: 3613MiB / 15827MiB
```

Wine version:wine-tkg-staging-fsync-git 9.2.r3.g29b947b8-327
Videocard driver: amdgpu(latest)
When crashed, even emergency reboot button on case doesn't work, i guess its cpu problem

Tried lowering cpu clock speed , didn't work

UPD: Tried running AIDA64 system stability test, check on stress cpu, fpu, cache, system memory and gpu and got crashed after 1:41:30 (1 hour 41 minutes 30 seconds), but on that crash i can use emergency reboot button, so now its gpu problem

Comment: what about non-game programs?

Comment: @jsotola didnt tried, I'll report you later

Comment: Report here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues

Comment: @jsotola Tried running AIDA64 system stability test, check on stress cpu, fpu, cache, system memory and gpu and got crashed after 1:41:30 (1 hour 41 minutes 30 seconds), but on that crash i can use emergency reboot button, so i guess its gpu

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov не думаю что это проблема в драйверах, но я оставил репорт

Comment: "even emergency reboot button on case doesn't work" this strongly indicates a HW or a driver issue. AMD engineers will hopefully figure it out.